# React controlled input inside iframe causes iframe to jump around and disappear onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile

I have an `iframe` that sits in a div that is `position: fixed;`.  This iframe loads a React application.  **On mobile browsers only**, any input inside this app that is controlled by React state causes some weird behavior whenever you try to type into the field.  Each input causes the div that is positioned to appear as if it is jumping off screen and then it disappears completely.  However, when I inspect, it still shows the inputs in their correct position and the cursor stays where it should and progresses as expected with each input.

I have confirmed that this only happens when the input is controlled by React state.  If I just do `<input type="text"/>`, it behaves as it should.

**Code:**

```
<div style="position:fixed;>
    <iframe src="/* my React application url */"><iframe>
</div>
```

**React:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
export default class App extends Component {
  state = { value: '' }

  changeInput = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      value: e.currentTarget.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      // This has no issues on mobile
      <input type="text"/>
      // This causes problems stated above
      <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.changeInput} />
    )
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please add in relevant code; there could be a large number of potential issues and its not possible to reliably diagnose without seeing the code.

Comment: @ChrisCousins Edited

Comment: Sorry to be a pain... can you also include the code wherein your react is actually included (the index.html) and rendered (at your top level react code, it will be calling a render function, being passed the id of the div into which to render your react app).

Comment: It is possible the click event (e) is causing issues higher up. You may wish to call an e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation() in your changeInput code, before the setState.